# Instagram API - Username instead of User-ID

Tags: objective-c, instagram, instagram-api

I am trying to get all recent posts of a specific user using Instagram API. I know that I can make a request like this:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

That being said, I do not know the user-id of a specific user. I would like to simply use the user's "username" instead of the user-id which I do not have. Can someone please help me to achieve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to get user photos by username

First make a user search api request:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q=
```

find the match for `username` in response and get the `user-id`, then make the recent media api request:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Comment: Thanks for this - was hoping it was possible in a single request but oh well :)